# stability of a difference equation

Tags: recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems, stability-theory

I would like some help in investigating the stablity of the difference equation 
$$
\begin{cases}
x_{n+1}=b   x_n e^{ay_n} \\ y_{n+1}=b   x_n (1-e^{-ay_n})
\end{cases}
$$ at (0,0).

I know that if b<1, then the variational matrix at (0,0) has 1 eigenvalue b,and in this case there is asymptotical stability.
but I do not know how to determine the stability in other cases.
thx in advance.

Comment: Is the term "difference equation" the good one ?

Comment: I apologize, but I do not understand what do you mean...

Comment: A difference equation isn't what you refer to (https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/2003/Probability/prob07.pdf). Moreover you should use the plural... (equation(s))